# Finding a word following two input words from txt file in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm making a dictionary where the keys are tuples of two consecutive words in a txt file and the value for each key is a list of words that were found directly following the key. For example,

```
>>> with open('alice.txt') as f: 
... d = associated_words(f) 
>>> d[('among', 'the')] 
>>> ['people', 'party.', 'trees,', 'distant', 'leaves,', 'trees', 'branches,', 'bright']
```

My code so far is below but it's not yet complete. Could someone help on this?

```
def associated_words(f):
    from collections import defaultdict    
    d = defaultdict(list)
    with open('alice.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().replace('\n', '') 

    a, b, c = [], [], []     
    lines.replace(",", "").replace(".", "")
    lines = line.split(" ")
    for (i, word) in enumerate(lines):
        d['something to replace'].append(lines[i+2])
```

Comment: what's the problem you're running into?

Comment: could you paste ur sample file here , just a a snippet

Comment: I understand the problem that you have but I would need a sample file to get formatting correctly! What are the empty lists a,b,c for?

Comment: Thanks for the comments :) I added the link for the file above.

Comment: Nobody asked for a link. Give a [mcve] *in the question itself*. And be more specific about the problem with your code; this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

something like this? (should be easily adaptable...)

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import defaultdict

DATA_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / '../data/alice.txt'

def next_word(fh):
    '''
    a generator that returns the next word from the file; with special
    characters removed; lower case.
    '''
    transtab = str.maketrans(',.`:;()?!—', '          ') # replace unwanted chars
    for line in fh.readlines():
        for word in line.translate(transtab).split():
            yield word.lower()

def handle_triplet(dct, triplet):
    '''
    add a triplet to the dictionary dct
    '''
    dct[(triplet[0], triplet[1])].append(triplet[2])

dct = defaultdict(list) # dictionary that defaults to []

with DATA_PATH.open('r') as fh:
    generator = next_word(fh)
    triplet = (next(generator), next(generator),  next(generator))
    handle_triplet(dct, triplet)
    for word in generator:
        triplet = (triplet[1], triplet[2], word)
        handle_triplet(dct, triplet)

print(dct)
```

output (excerpt...; not run on the whole text)

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
    ('enough', 'under'): ['her'], ('rattle', 'of'): ['the'],
    ('suppose', 'they'): ['are'], ('flung', 'down'): ['his'],
    ('make', 'with'): ['the'], ('ring', 'and'): ['begged'],
    ('taken', 'his'): ['watch'], ('could', 'show'): ['you'],
    ('said', 'tossing'): ['his'], ('a', 'bottle'): ['marked', 'they'],
    ('dead', 'silence'): ['instantly', 'alice', "'it's"], ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you file looks like this

```
each them theirs tree life what not hope
```

Code:

```
lines = [line.strip().split(' ') for line in open('test.txt')]

d = {}
for each in lines:
    d[(each[0],each[1])] = each[2:]
print d
```